# MySQL: Select only the earliest date found in a set

Tags: php, mysql

I have to write an export function that creates a CSV file of shop-orders, that have specific statuses attached to them within a specific timeframe. The problem is, that one kind of status (like status ID 32) can appear multiple times within the same order, but only the earliest added status is relevant.

This is my code so far:

```
select * FROM orders_status_history
JOIN orders_total ON (
    orders_total.orders_id = orders_status_history.orders_id 
    AND orders_total.class = "ot_total"
)
JOIN orders ON (
    orders.orders_id = orders_status_history.orders_id
)
WHERE orders_status_history.orders_status_id IN(32, 21, 56, 45)
  AND orders_status_history.date_added >= "' . $start . '" 
  AND orders_status_history.date_added <= "' . $end . '"
```

This already works as expected, **the goal is to only return a record when the matching status was also the earliest added to the order.**

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple additive to your sql. At the end add

```
ORDER BY orders_status_history.date_added Limit 0,1
```